# Magento 2.4.2 Free Shipping for some items by sku or category

Tags: shipping, magento2.4.2

**Magento 2.4.2
Cart Price Rules**
Free Shipping on only select few items not working when non free ship sku is added to cart.

**Rule Name:** name
**Active:** true
**Coupon:** No
**Customer Groups:** ALL
**Websites:** All

**Conditions:** Blank All items

**Actions:**
**Apply:** Percent of product price discount
**Discount Amount:** 0
**Max Qty:** 0
**Discount Qty Step:** 1
**Apply to Shipping Amount:** Yes
**Discard Subsequent rules:** No

**Apply the Rule only to cart items matching the following conditions:**
I have
SKU is one of SKU1,SKU2,SKU3

**Free Shipping:** For shipment with matching items
[image]

**Configuration -> Sales -> Delivery Methods
FREE SHIPPING**
**Enabled :**No
If I enable this it always show free shipping.  I do not want this option.  I have seen many post saying enable this.
[image]

**I use USPS shipping module that is built in with Magento 2.4.2**
**Free Method:** Priority Mail  (which is enabled in allowed methods)
**Enable Free Shipping Threshold:** Disable
[image]

**STEPS**

1. I add SKU4 to cart
2. Put in a location US CO 80014
3. USPS priority mail show $12.60  (Works Great)
4. Add SKU1 (frees ship Sku) to cart which and adds onto the shipping cost. $0.60 from $12.60 to $13.20
5. Remove SKU4 the shipping price Drops back to free.

**WHAT is suppose to happen: **
When SKU4 is in cart alone charge shipping.  This works $12.60 for SKU4
***When SKU1 is added to cart with SKU4 shipping should still be the same.  $12.60 but it changes to $13.20***
When SKU1 is in cart $0.00 Shipping.  This works

**SKU4 Not in RULE so this picture is correct charge shipping.**
[image]

**SKU4 and added SKU1:** SKU1 is free ship so it should still be the shipping for SKU4 only not SKU1's add-on cost.
[image]

**Remove SKU4 and Free Shipping works**
With SKU4 removed SKU1 now is free shipping.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by Magento core module.

It occurs on all versions of Magento in both the ce and ee versions.

If you add only 1 SKU your rule will work, but when you add two or more SKU it won't work.

Comment: hi there, can you back this up with some links to some references to this issue?

Comment: @LitExtension Magento Migration  Do you know of an extension to work around this?

Comment: I have found an article for this problem. They say the problem has been solved but it never completely solved the problem, the same error still occurs on the latest version of magento today.
You can refer to the article: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21269

Comment: @LitExtension Magento Migration  This is not an issue in 2.4.2.  You did not understand my issue.   I tested multiple skus and adding SKU1, SKU2 to the cart the free shipping still shows. Only adding a non free sku the free ones weights are used with the non free.

Comment: I am very sorry if my answer leaves you unsatisfied.
However, for your problem it is not possible to apply multiple sku when creating the catalog price rule (I have sent the documentation to you and there is confirmation that this problem is caused by magento's core module).
Also I tested on my environment with the latest version of magento (2.4.2) and I found that this issue is still not resolved.